# Magic 8 Ball with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a "Magic 8 Ball" with HTML/Javascript. I have been tried to fiddle with the code and I am going to continue to add/play with things, but if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. If I figure it out I will update the post, however I am currently stuck at this point.

The point of the program is that a user can type a question, then whenever the 8-Ball image gets clicked one of the random answers will appear below the 8-ball image.

I think my error is in the "response=RandomOneOf....." lines.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- =================================================== -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Magic-8 Ball </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="random.js">
            function GenerateAnswer()
            {
                response = RandomOneOf([
                    'It is certain',
                    'Without a doubt',
                    'Most likely',
                    'Yes',
                    'Reply hazy try again',
                    'Ask again later',
                    'My reply is no',
                    'No',
                    'Very doubtful',
                    ]);
                document.getElementById('magicBallButton').onclick = function GenerateAnswer();
                document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 
                    + response +;

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <h1>Magic 8-Ball (Mattel, Inc.)</h1>
            <br>
            Enter a question below, then click on the Magic 8-Ball to recieve its wisdom.
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="questionBox" size=100 value=''>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="image" src="8ball.png" alt="magicBall" id="magicBallButton" onclick="GenerateAnswer()";>
        </div>
        <div id="outputDiv"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a question and answer platform where you ask a specific question about a specific problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Concentrate and ask again

Comment: you can't put script inside `script` tags with an `src` attribute. The inner script is ignored and the src code is run. [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems  with your script:

1. You are calling an external script with `<script src>` and then adding inline script below that. External scripts should have an independent `<script>` tag.
2. You are calling `GenerateAnswer` on click of `#magicBallButton`
   (`<input id="magicBallButton" onclick="GenerateAnswer()"`), but also attempting to do so with `document.getElementById('magicBallButton').onclick = function GenerateAnswer();`. Not only is this redundant, but you shouldn't specify `function` in a function **evocation**.
3. `document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = +response + ;` is horribly invalid syntax. You're looking for `document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = response`.
4. `RandomOneOf` an array appears to be undefined. You can get a random response from the array with `response = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];`. Note that I removed the brackets surrounding the original array, and renamed it to `responses` (because it contains **all** of the possible responses, not just the desired one).

Here's a working example, with all of the above points corrected:

```js
function GenerateAnswer() {
  responses = [
    'It is certain',
    'Without a doubt',
    'Most likely',
    'Yes',
    'Reply hazy try again',
    'Ask again later',
    'My reply is no',
    'No',
    'Very doubtful',
  ];
  response = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Magic 8-Ball (Mattel, Inc.)</h1>
    <br> Enter a question below, then click on the Magic 8-Ball to recieve its wisdom.
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="questionBox" size=100 value=''>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="8ball.png" alt="magicBall" id="magicBallButton" onclick="GenerateAnswer()" ;>
  </div>
  <div id="outputDiv"> </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been trying to figure this out for hours. :D